# Move the location of a button in django forms and html

Tags: html, django

I have a 2 buttons; a sign in button and a register button. Its part of a registration form made in `Django`. The buttons are meant to be aligned, as in same level but they are not as seen in the picture below. How would I fix this?

[image: image of problem]

from the html:

```
<div class="card-content">
<form id="teacher-register-form" action="{% url 'teacher-register' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form|bootstrap }}
   <span></span>
   <br/>
   <br/><!-- an attempt to bridge the gap between the buttons. -->
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">{% trans "Register" %}</button>
</form>
<span>{% trans "If you have an account" %}</span>
<br />
<a href="{% url 'teacher-login' %}" class="btn btn-primary">{% trans "Init session" %}</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is insert both buttons into the form maybe.

```
 <div class="card-content">
    <form id="teacher-register-form" action="{% url 'teacher-register' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form|bootstrap }}
       <span></span>
       <br/>
       <br/><!-- an attempt to bridge the gap between the buttons. -->
       <span>{% trans "If you have an account" %}</span>
       <br />
       <a href="{% url 'teacher-login' %}" class="btn btn-primary">{% trans "Init session" %}</a>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">{% trans "Register" %}</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! Worked a peach! should have thought of that!